# Regex exclude ASCII characters from (HEX value) 7F to FF

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to do Regex for password validation and I have the following requirements:

- the password should contain at least 1 upper character
- the password should contain at least 1 lower character
- the password should contain at least 1 number
- the password should contain at least 1 special character
- all the characters in the password should be in range from 20 to 7E (ASCII HEX value) which means not including diacritics and other symbols.

So far I've come up with this REGEX:

```
^(?=[\x20-\x7E])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*(?<=.[\x20-\x7E])$
```

When I test it, it fails for 2/3 and I can't make it fail for the last one - when some of the characters not in the range is in the middle of the password. For first and last is OK. Take a look at [Test regex img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoO2M.png). Any thoughts on how to make it work?

Comment: Why does it have to be a single regex?

Comment: @stark Is it possible to do it in a single regex?

Comment: `^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9])[\x20-\xFF]+$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the last part still not OK :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually this worked OK for me. Thank you :)

`^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9])[\x20-\x7E]+$`

Comment: Well, it was not clear from your question: you asked for the chars to be in the `7F to FF` range.

Comment: @VasilKarakulev If it works for you then you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9])[\x20-\x7E]+$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - at least one uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - at least one lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` - at least one ASCII digit
- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9])` - at least one char other than ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `[\x20-\x7E]+` - one or more chars in the `\x20` and `\x7E` range
- `$` - end of string.